# Different types assignment in switch state cases, inside template function

Tags: c++

Apple.h

```
class Apple {
public:
    Apple(int);
    static int typeID;
private:
    int id_;
};
```

Apple.cpp

```
#include "Apple.h"
Apple::Apple(int pID) {
    id_ = pID;
}
```

Potato.h, Potato.cpp identical to Apple

Storage.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Apple.h"
#include "Potato.h"
#include <vector>
class Storage {
public:
    Storage();
    template<typename foodName> void store(foodName * object){
        (*getBasket<foodName>()).push_back(object);
    };
    template<typename foodName> int countSize(){
        return (*getBasket<foodName>()).size();
    };

private:
    std::vector<Apple*> applebasket_;
    std::vector<Potato*> potatobasket_;
    template <typename foodName> std::vector<foodName*> * getBasket(){
        std::vector<foodName*> * result;
        switch(foodName::typeID){
            case 0:
                result = &applebasket_;
                break;
            case 1:
                //result = &potatobasket_;
                break;
        }
        return result;
    } 
};
```

Storage.cpp

```
#include "Storage.h"
int Apple::typeID;
int Potato::typeID;
Storage::Storage() {
    Apple::typeID = 0;
    Potato::typeID =1;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Storage.h"
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Apple* apple;
    Potato* potato;
    Storage storage;
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < 7;i++){
        apple = new Apple(i);
        storage.store<Apple>(apple);  
    }      
    std::cout<<storage.countSize<Apple>();
    return 0;
}
```

This code works and outputs right size of vector, but if case line in switch statement (inside Storage.h) is uncommented, compiler(g++) throws 
"error: cannot convert ‘std::vector < Potato*>* ' to 'std::vector< Apple*>* ' in assignment". 
It is like compiler trying out both cases anyway, and i cant find is it possible and how to avoid this. 
I need help with this and maybe some advice on a whole thing(one interface for containers of different types), I've started learning C++ recently and probably the way i try this to do here is a total mess.

Comment: You **certainly** should not set the `typeID` in the `Storage` constructor. But +1 for an interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because both `case` should compile which is not possible, as the type differs in both `case`.

One solution to this problem is to use overload instead of function template as (which means, there is NO need of `typeID` in your class!) :

```
std::vector<Apple*> * get_basket(Apple *)
{
   return &applebasket_;  //return pointer to the apple basket
}

std::vector<Potato*> * get_basket(Potato *)
{
   return &potatobasket_; //return pointer to the potate basket
}
```

And call it as:

```
template<typename FoodType> 
void store(FoodType * object)
{
    std::vector<FoodType> * basket = get_basket(static_cast<FoodType*>(0));
    basket->push_back(object);
}
```

The trick here is that you have two overloads, each takes one argument of *different* type, and so you use `static_cast<FoodType*>(0)` to help the compiler to pick the correct overload based on the *type* of the expression `static_cast<FoodType*>(0)` which would be either of type `Apple*` or `Potato*`.

---

@Gorpik [said in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11035109/415784) that both (this as well as other solution) are ugly, so here is another attempt to solve this problem.

Define a `base_storage` class template as:

```
template<typename FoodType>
class base_storage
{
    std::vector<FoodType*> m_storage;
    public:
        void store(FoodType *foodItem)
        {
            m_storage.push_back(foodItem);
        }
        size_t count() const
        {
            return m_storage.size();
        }
};
```

This base class stores food items of *one* type only, but in the question, we need to store food items of *two* types. So in order to do that, lets define another class `Storage` deriving from the above class template as:

```
class storage : private base_storage<Apple>, private base_storage<Potato>
{
    public:
        template<typename FoodType> 
        void store(FoodType * foodItem)
        {
            base_storage<FoodType>::store(foodItem);
        }
        template<typename FoodType> 
        size_t count() const
        {
            return base_storage<FoodType>::count();
        }
};
```

Note two points here:

- The class `storage` doesn't have any member data now. It just forward the call to the base class which is chosen based on the type of template argument `FoodType`.
- It derives *privately* from the base classes. So it is not `is-a` relationship.

See the online demo of this solution here : http://ideone.com/Ykjo5

The beauty of this solution is that if you want to make it work for *three* types of food, then all you need to derive it from *three* base classes as:

```
class storage : private base_storage<Apple>, 
                private base_storage<Potato>,
                private base_storage<Mango>   //added line!
{

     //same as before; no change at all !

};
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/lnMds

Comment: @Человек Ящерица: See the alternative solution.

Comment: I think this is an elegant way. I'll use it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need even to use typeID field. Let compiler to do all job.

```
class Storage {
public:
    Storage();
    template<typename foodName> void store(foodName * object){
        (*getBasket<foodName>()).push_back(object);
    };
    template<typename foodName> int countSize(){
        return (*getBasket<foodName>()).size();
    };

private:
    std::vector<Apple*> applebasket_;
    std::vector<Potato*> potatobasket_;

    template <typename foodName> std::vector<foodName*> * getBasket();
};


template <> std::vector<Apple*> * Storage::getBasket()
{
    return &applebasket_;
} 
template <> std::vector<Potato*> * Storage::getBasket()
{
    return &potatobasket_;
}
```

Comment: please remove the ; at the end of getBacket() specializations.

Comment: [Function template specialization is NOT a good thing.](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: It gives me "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class Storage’" on two lines with  getBasket() , already found thread about this error check this out later.

Comment: @Nawaz: I agree with you, but the alternative you propose is quite ugly on the caller side. Neither solution satisfies me completely, though I don't see better alternatives.

Comment: @Nawaz In this case there no anything bad with specializing function template. Because non-specialized template funtion is not implemented. Also you can't solve this problem by overloading because only returning values differs.

Comment: @Nawaz Your solution is Ok =) as mine is Ok too.

Comment: @Nawaz, yours solution is at the cost of an unused parameter.

Comment: @Gorpik: See the alternative solution in my answer.

Comment: @Nawaz: I like the alternative much better.

Comment: @Gorpik: Thanks. :-) ... *(Even I liked that for the obvious reason)*

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<Apple *>` and `std::vector<Potato *>` are different types. C++ templates produce a complete copy of the class definition and all its code at compile time, so there's no relationship between the resultant concrete types at all.

If `Apple` and `Potato` shared a common parent class, say `Food` you could store both kinds of thing in a `std::vector<Food *>`, but you still wouldn't be able to return a `std::vector<Apple *>` where a `std::vector<Food *>` was expected.

Your `getBasket()` method attempts to get around this by templating the return type, but it can't because templates are evaluated at *compile time* while the switch statement is evaluated at *run time*. The compiler has to decide what the `foodStuff` parameter is before the program even begins to run, and so it has no idea what the outcome of that switch statement might be. Yet it has to make a decision anyway, and it's gone for the result it can derive from the first `return` statement it finds in the function body, with the unfortunate consequence that the second one is then invalid.

So, you need to either store and retrieve `Apple`s and `Potato`s separately (possibly using templating as some of the other answers have suggested), or use inheritance so that you can store them in something which understands a common parent type.

Answer (score 0):

Specialize `getBasket` for the two cases.

Or better, don't mix abstration levels this way, and just provide separate potato and apple containers.